# Implemented Selenium Parallel run using Thread Local but While closing driver using driver manager,it is getting wrong driverID.Hence Tests are failed

Tags: java, selenium

Almost i used below reference link to implement the Parallel Run in my project.

https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/

When driver done its part and went to closing part , i am using DriverManager to getDriver() but at this time i getting wrong driverID which is leading to close wrong window and ending up with failures .

My code :-

```java
@Listeners({ SeleniumScreenshotOnFailureListener.class,SystemScreenshotOnFailureListener.class })
public abstract class DefaultTestSet {
    /* protected EmergyaWebDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(); */

    private Initialization config = Initialization.getInstance();

    protected ScreenRecorder screenRecorder;
    protected String tcName = "";
    private String failedSuitePath = "src/main/resources/suites/emergyaFailedTest.xml";

    public Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DefaultTestSet.class);

    @BeforeMethod
    public void nameBefore(Method method) {
        this.tcName = method.getName();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before() {
        EmergyaWebDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver();

        driver = config.initialize();
        DriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);

        if (driver != null && config.isRecordVideo() == true) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                log.info("Recording video");

                GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice()
                    .getDefaultConfiguration();

                this.screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(gc, null,
                    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
                        new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                            CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE, DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey,
                                Rational.valueOf(15), QualityKey, 1.0f, KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
                                    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black", FrameRateKey,
                                        Rational.valueOf(30)),
                                            null, new File(config.getVideoRecordingPath()));

                screenRecorder.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn("Recorder could not be initilized. No video will be recording");
            }
            log.info("Start recording in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
        } else {
            log.info("No video recording");
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void afterAllIsSaidAndDone() {
        EmergyaWebDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver();

        log.info("Function afterAllIsSaidAndDone");
        DriverManager.closeDriver(driver);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void recordVideo(ITestResult result) {
        EmergyaWebDriver driver = DriverManager.getDriver();

        if (driver != null && (config.isRecordVideo() == true) && (screenRecorder != null)
        && (screenRecorder.getState().equals(State.RECORDING))) {

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            try {
                screenRecorder.stop();
                log.info("Recorder stoped");
                File tempRecordeFile = screenRecorder.getCreatedMovieFiles().get(0);

                if ((!config.isSaveVideoForPassed()) && (result.getStatus() == 1)) {
                    log.info("Test passed. Deleting video");

                    if (tempRecordeFile.delete()) {
                        log.info("File deleted");
                    } else {
                        log.warn("Video could not be deleted");
                    }
                } else {
                    String endPath = tempRecordeFile.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("ScreenRecording", this.tcName);
                    if (tempRecordeFile.renameTo(new File(endPath))) {
                        log.info("File stored in " + endPath);
                    } else {
                        log.warn("Video could not be stored in " + endPath);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.warn("Recorder could not be stoped");
            }

            log.info("Recording video took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void checkFailedTest(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getMethod().getXmlTest().getName().equals("FailedTests")) {
            removePassedTestToXML(result.getMethod().getRealClass().getName(), result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        } else {
            log.info("checkFailedTest.........result status of test is: " + result.getStatus());

            if (result.getStatus() == 2) {
                log.info("name Of the xml TestSuite is " + result.getMethod().getXmlTest().getName());

                if (!result.getMethod().getXmlTest().getName().equals("Default test")) {
                    addFailedTestToXML(result.getMethod().getRealClass().getName(), result.getMethod().getMethodName());
                }
            } else if (!result.getMethod().getXmlTest().getName().equals("Default test")) {
                removePassedTestToXML(result.getMethod().getRealClass().getName(), result.getMethod().getMethodName());
            }
        }
    }

    // *** Public methods ***//
    /**
        * Obtains the initialization configuration
        *
        * @return initialization instance
        */
    public synchronized Initialization getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    /**
        * Method to get a timestamp
        *
        * @return string with the timestamp
        */
    public static String getTimeStamp() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        return timeStamp;
    }

    // *** Private methods ***//
    /**
        * Method to add failed test to a xml file
        *
        * @param suite
        *            name
        * @param testName
        *            name of the test
        */
    private synchronized void addFailedTestToXML(String suite, String testName) {
        try {
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.build(new FileInputStream(failedSuitePath));

            Element foundElement = (Element) XPath.selectSingleNode(doc,
                "/suite/test/classes/class[@name='" + suite + "']/methods/include[@name='" + testName + "']");

            if (foundElement == null) {
                Element foundClass = (Element) XPath.selectSingleNode(doc,
                    "/suite/test/classes/class[@name='" + suite + "']");

                if (foundClass != null) {
                    // Adding the method element
                    Element methodsElement = foundClass.getChild("methods");

                    // Adding the include element with the test name
                    Element includeElement = new Element("include");
                    includeElement.setAttribute("name", testName);
                    methodsElement.addContent(includeElement);

                    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
                    xmlOutput.setFormat(org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
                    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter(failedSuitePath));
                } else {
                    Element rootElement = doc.getRootElement();

                    Element testElement = rootElement.getChild("test");

                    Element classesElement = testElement.getChild("classes");

                    // Adding the class element with the testSet name
                    Element classElement = new Element("class");
                    classElement.setAttribute("name", suite);
                    classesElement.addContent(classElement);

                    // Adding the method element
                    Element methodsElement = new Element("methods");
                    classElement.addContent(methodsElement);

                    // Adding the include element with the test name
                    Element includeElement = new Element("include");
                    includeElement.setAttribute("name", testName);
                    methodsElement.addContent(includeElement);

                    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
                    xmlOutput.setFormat(org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
                    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter(failedSuitePath));
                }
            } else {
                log.info("The test is already added in the xml of failed tests");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
        * Method to remove passed test of the xml file
        *
        * @param suite
        *            name
        * @param testName
        *            name of the test
        */
    private synchronized void removePassedTestToXML(String suite, String testName) {
        try {
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.build(new FileInputStream(failedSuitePath));

            Element rootElement = doc.getRootElement();
            Element testElement = rootElement.getChild("test");
            Element classesElement = testElement.getChild("classes");
            Element test = (Element) XPath.selectSingleNode(doc,
                "/suite/test/classes/class[@name='" + suite + "']/methods/include[@name='" + testName + "']");
            if (test != null) {
                if (XPath.selectNodes(doc, "/suite/test/classes/class[@name='" + suite + "']/methods/include")
                .size() > 1) {

                    Element testToRemove = (Element) XPath.selectSingleNode(doc, "/suite/test/classes/class[@name='"
                        + suite + "']/methods/include[@name='" + testName + "']");
                    Element methodElement = (Element) XPath.selectSingleNode(doc,
                        "/suite/test/classes/class[@name='" + suite + "']/methods");

                    methodElement.removeContent(testToRemove);
                    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
                    xmlOutput.setFormat(org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
                    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter(failedSuitePath));
                } else {
                    classesElement.removeContent(test.getParentElement().getParentElement());
                    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
                    xmlOutput.setFormat(org.jdom.output.Format.getPrettyFormat());
                    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter(failedSuitePath));
                }

            } else {
                log.info("The test not exists in the xml of failed tests");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
        * Checks that the PO is ready
        *
        * @param pageObject
        *            page object to be used
        */
    protected synchronized void isReady(BasePageObject pageObject) {
        assertTrue("The PO " + pageObject.getClass().getName() + " is not ready", pageObject.isReady());
    }
}
```

Driver Manager:-

```java
package com.opentext.selenium.drivers;

public class DriverManager {
    private static final ThreadLocal<EmergyaWebDriver> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EmergyaWebDriver>();

    public synchronized static EmergyaWebDriver getDriver() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }

    public synchronized static void setWebDriver(EmergyaWebDriver driver) {
        threadLocal.set(driver);

    }

    public synchronized static void closeDriver(EmergyaWebDriver driver) {

        driver = getDriver();
        if (driver != null) {
            try {
                driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                driver.quit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        threadLocal.remove();

    }
}
```

initialize:-

```
public EmergyaWebDriver initialize() {
log.info("[log-Properties] " + this.getClass().getName() + "- Start initialize test");

// tmpDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();

EmergyaWebDriver driver = null;

// Driver initialization
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", webdriverFireFox + ".exe");
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", true);
    firefoxProfile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", this.getDownloadPath());
    capability.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla  Firefox\\msfirefox.exe"); // for
    // windows
    capability.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);

    File dir = new File(this.getDownloadPath());
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    String mimeTypes = getMimeTypes();

    // adding mimetypes
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", mimeTypes);
    // forcing the downloads
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", mimeTypes);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);

    firefoxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

    /*
     * tempdriver = new InheritableThreadLocal<EmergyaWebDriver>() {
     * 
     * @Override protected EmergyaFirefoxDriver initialValue() {
     * EmergyaFirefoxDriver fireFoxDriver = new
     * EmergyaFirefoxDriver(capability); tempdrivers.add(fireFoxDriver);
     * return fireFoxDriver; } };
     */

    driver = new EmergyaFirefoxDriver(capability);

} else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    if (os.equalsIgnoreCase("windows")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", webdriverChrome + ".exe");
    } else {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", webdriverChrome + ".exe");
    }

    /*
     * tempdriver = new InheritableThreadLocal<EmergyaWebDriver>() {
     * 
     * @Override protected EmergyaChromeDriver initialValue() {
     * EmergyaChromeDriver chromeDriver = new
     * EmergyaChromeDriver(capabilities); tempdrivers.add(chromeDriver);
     * return chromeDriver; } };
     */
    driver = new EmergyaChromeDriver(capabilities);

} else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE") && os.equalsIgnoreCase("windows")) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", webdriverIE);

    /*
     * tempdriver = new InheritableThreadLocal<EmergyaWebDriver>() {
     * 
     * @Override protected EmergyaIEDriver initialValue() {
     * EmergyaIEDriver ieDriver = new EmergyaIEDriver();
     * tempdrivers.add(ieDriver); return ieDriver; } };
     */

    driver = new EmergyaIEDriver();
}

log.info("Browser initialized with dimensions: " + driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth() + "px X "
        + driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() + "px");

widthBeforeMaximize = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
heightBeforeMaximize = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();

driver.get(loginURL);

driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);

driver.sleep(1);

widthAfterMaximize = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
heightAfterMaximize = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();

if ((widthBeforeMaximize == widthAfterMaximize) && (heightBeforeMaximize == heightAfterMaximize)) {
    log.info("Not maximized first time...try again");

    driver.sleep(1);

    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);

    driver.sleep(2);
}

this.cleanDownloadDirectory();

log.info("Browser resized with dimensions: " + driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth() + "px X "
        + driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight() + "px");

log.info("[log-Properties] " + this.getClass().getName() + "- End initialize test");

System.out.println(driver);
return driver;
```

}

Comment: The blog that you quoted is mine. Can you please show us what does your `Initialization` class look like ? Ideally speaking, you should have a factory method that creates `WebDriver` instances and then puts them into the current Thread context via the `DriverManager.setWebDriver()` call (This method doesn't need to be `synchronized` because you are persisting data into a `ThreadLocal`, so there's no need for locking)

Comment: Added Initialization method in above Question

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan... Any help would be great ...

Comment: The code is still hard to read because its not complete. Also you are stating that you are getting the wrong driver id. Where are you getting it ? How are you ascertaining it. You still can help clean up the code that you shared to remove off all the noise and trim it to a simple sample to help understand your issue.I can't get your code into an IDE due to all the missing classes/method references etc.,